# C# static data hierarchy

Tags: c#, structure

Is there any way to create a static hierarchy with values? For example there is one "baseclass" named "Layer1", one "subclasses" of Layer one (Layer two) and a static string named value1 (in layer2).
My goal is now to access the data via the command:

```cs
currentValue = Layer1.Layer2.Value1
```

so without creating an object of a non static class. You can't extend a static class but is there any workaround?

Comment: Singleton maybe?

Comment: Some more context might be helpful - what problem are you trying to solve with this (why do they need to be static)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make the ***class*** `static`, only the variable.

Example:

```
public class Class1
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public static string String1 = "a";
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    string s = Class1.Class2.String1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ^^